# Indentation missing for algorithm package in documentclass{minimal}

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am trying to get write an algorithm in LaTeX for `minimal` document class. Unfortunately, the indentation is completely missing.
Following is my sample code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{pslatex}

\special{papersize=36in,24in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{36in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24in}
\topskip0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
 read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
 go to next section\;
 current section becomes this one\;
 }{
 go back to the beginning of current section\;
 }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This is how it currently appears using document class - `minimal`:

[image]

This is how want it to appear:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The `minimal` class misses a lot of definitions that you would take for granted. Do you really have to use that class? If so, why? There may be a workaround using a more complete class, such as `article`.

Comment: The `minimal` class is not really meant for real documents; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42115/8528).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minimal` document class is the problem, since two important lengths are not updated properly. They are `\skiptext` and `\skiprule`. Setting these to the defaults:

```
\setlength{\skiptext}{10pt}
\setlength{\skiprule}{5pt}
```

restores the alignment. Other things may also require updating, which all points to not using `minimal` in general. `article` would work just as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\setlength{\skiptext}{10pt}
\setlength{\skiprule}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
 read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
 go to next section\;
 current section becomes this one\;
 }{
 go back to the beginning of current section\;
 }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```